# how to return float array from a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return

The output shows the values of `k` as `0.000` but it should contain actual values that are returned from `funcTest()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *funcTest(int *a, int size)
{
    float p[size];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++){
        p[i] = *a;
        p[i]=p[i]/2;
        a++;
    }
    for(i =0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%f\n",p[i]);
    }
    return (float *)p;
}

int main()
{
    int a[4] = {1,5,3,7};
    int size = 4;
    int i,j;
    float *k;
    k = funcTest(&a[0],size);
    for(i =0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%f\n",*k);
        k++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
0.5
2.5
1.5
3.5
1.5
0.000
0.000
0.000
```

Comment: p will be destroyed once you leave the method "functest". Therefore the pointer you receive is not valid at all.

Answer (score 3):

You return a local variable. so, at end of function, local variables are cleaned and do not exist any more. You should use `malloc`

```
float *funcTest(int *a, int size)
{
    float *p = malloc(sizeof(float) * size);
```

And don't forget to free memory when you don't use it anymore with `free`. If you forget, you will have a memory leak

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `float p[size];` is local to the function `funcTest()`, so you cannot return the address of it from the function and expect it to be valid in the caller. Once the `funcTest()` function ends, `p` will cease to exist. Then, any attempt to make use of the return value will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because of invalid memory access.

Instead, you can make `p` a pointer, allocate memory dynamically using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family and then, return that pointer to the caller. Dynamically allocated memory will have a lifetime equal to the entire execution of the program (*unless deallocated manually*), so, even after returning from the function, in the caller, the returned pointer will be valid.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is an automatic local variable and will no longer be exist once function return. Returning a pointer to it will invoke undefined behavior.

Allocate `p` dynamically

```
float *p = malloc(size*sizeof(float));
```

Free the allocated memory once you are done with it

```
float *k;
k = funcTest(&a[0],size);
if(k == NULL)             // Check for null pointer
    exit(0);
float *temp = k;
for(i =0; i<size; i++){
    printf("%f\n",*k);
    k++;
}
free(temp);              // Free allocated memory
return 0;
```

Comment: @SouvikKundu don't forget to free memory when you don't need it anymore. If you forget, you will have a memory leak

Answer (score 2):

As the people before me pointed out, you're trying to return a stack allocated variable (a local variable in a function), meaning the memory you point to isn't valid once the function exits (it clears out on some implementations, but really it's behavior isn't defined).

The solution is to either use `malloc`, as pointed out before, OR pass a pointer to the function (thus avoiding `malloc` and `free`), keeping the allocation on the stack of the calling function.

i.e. (this might not work, it isn't tested, just here for demonstration of the idea):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int funcTest(float *p, int *a, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++){
        p[i] = *a;
        p[i]=p[i]/2;
        a++;
    }
    for(i =0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%f\n",p[i]);
    }
    // we can use the return value for errors.
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[4] = {1,5,3,7};
    float p[4] = {0};
    int size = 4;
    int i;
    funcTest(p, a, size);
    for(i =0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%f\n",p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice also, you don't need to use `&a[0]` - arrays are pointers at heart, so `a` is the memory address of `a[0]` while `a + 1` is the memory address of `a[1]`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Note: There is no need to return the array. Just print `p` directly from `main`.

Comment: @CoolGuy - Yap, you're right. I didn't even look at that part of the code ... I'll fix this up :-)

Comment: Also, no need for funcTest to return something, could be `void funcTest(float *p, int *a, int size)`

Comment: @Garf365 , yap, that's true here, but it's good practice to use error check, so I left a `return 0` to nudge in the right direction... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funcTest(int *a, int size, float *output)
{
    output = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * size);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++){
        output[i] = *a;
        output[i]=output[i]/2;
        a++;
    }
    for(i =0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%f\n",output[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[4] = {1,5,3,7};
    int size = 4;
    int i,j;
    float *k;
    funcTest(&a[0],size, k);
    for(i =0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%f\n",k);
        k++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This might be worked.

1. Remove your local definition **float p[size];** in **funcTest**
2. Add one more parameter **float *output** in your **funcTest** for **output** pointer.
3. Allocate memory, malloc the **sizeof(float) * size** for your **output** pointer (float array size) in **funcTest**.
4. Replace variable **p** into the parameter **output**.
5. No need to return, change return type from **float *** to **void**.
6. Fix into **printf("%f\n",k)**; k is a address. *k is a pointer.